# Product of i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed on $(-1,1)$ converges almost surely to $0$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $(X_n)$ i.i.d. random variables with uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$. If $Y_n=X_1\ldots X_n$, prove that $(Y_n)$ converges to $0$ a.s.

Comment: Another approach than the two valid ones already posted on the page is to note that $\log|Y_n|$ is the sum of $n$ i.i.d. random variables $\log|X_k|$, each with mean $E(\log|X_1|)<0$, hence the law of large numbers ensures that $\frac1n\log|Y_n|$ has a negative almost sure limit--and this is more than enough to get the desired conclusion.

Comment: Still another approach is to note that $E\left(\sum\limits_n|Y_n|\right)=\sum\limits_nE(|X_1|)^n$ is finite since $E(|X_1|)<1$ hence the series $\sum\limits_n|Y_n|$ is finite almost surely hence $Y_n\to0$ almost surely.

Comment: @Did Nice! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Did, very good (multi)approaches to the task! Great job!Thanks a lot!

Comment: And yet another one (the thing is a goldmine...): since $(|Y_n|)$ is almost surely decreasing, it converges almost surely to some random variable $L$; since $Y_{n+1}=X_1Y'_n$ where $(Y'_n)$ is distributed as $(Y_n)$ and independent of $X_1$, $|Y_{n+1}|\to|X_1|\cdot L'$ almost surely, where $L'$ is distributed as $L$ and independent of $X_1$ hence $E(L)=E(|X_1|\cdot L')=E(|X_1|)\cdot E(L)$, which implies $E(L)=0$ because $E(|X_1|)<1$, hence $L=0$ almost surely since $L\geqslant0$ almost surely by construction.

Comment: Tools of the reals, applied to ramdom variables / distributions. Great job @Did!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Borel-Cantelli lemma, if the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{|Y_n|>\varepsilon\}
$$
converges for each $\varepsilon>0$, $Y_n\to0$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$. Using Chebyshev's inequality,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{|Y_n|>\varepsilon\}
\le\frac1{\varepsilon^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\operatorname E|Y_n|^2
$$
since $\operatorname EY_n=0$. By independence,
$$
\operatorname E|Y_n|^2=\operatorname E|X_1|^2\ldots\operatorname E|X_n|^2.
$$
We have that
$$
E|X_1|^2=\frac{(1-(-1))^2}{12}=\frac13.
$$
Hence,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty P\{|Y_n|>\varepsilon\}
\le\frac1{\varepsilon^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\biggl(\frac13\biggr)^n<\infty
$$
for each $\varepsilon>0$ and $Y_n\to0$ almost surely as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Why do you have squares appearing for Markov's inequality?(there would be if you consider $\mathbb{P}\{Y_n^2 > \varepsilon^2\}$, which you can (even if it does not add much to the argument); but then the squares are within the expectation, and so you should compute $\mathbb{E}[X_1^2]$, not $\mathbb{E}[\lvert X_1\rvert]$.)

Comment: @ClementC. The Wikipedia page for Markov's inequality gives a more general version: if $\phi$ is a monotonically increasing function from the nonnegative reals to the nonnegative reals, then $P(|X| \geq a) \leq \frac{E[\phi(|X|)]}{\phi(a)}$.  Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality

Comment: That is true -- and easy to show from the "regular" Markov, but you don't need it, really. $\frac{\mathbb{E}[\lvert Y_n\rvert]}{\varepsilon}$ would do the job as well. (My comment, besides the typo, was mostly to ask if there was a specific reason to choose to square the quantities.)

Comment: @ClementC. By Markov's inequality I mean this general inequality pointed out by user46944 and Chebyshev's inequality is a special case of Markov's inequality. I used the second moment since I knew the variance of a uniform distribution. I think other absolute moments would work too.

Comment: Yes, I saw that after the edit... the appearance of the squares makes "logical" sense if the idea was to use Chebyshev, as it's now clear it was (vanilla-Markov, as simpler/requiring less assumption on the r.v., seemed the natural choice when i read your answer, and then I was intrigued by the choice of applying it after the squaring -- again, this is completely valid, but seemed to me like an unnecessary step.) Without the squaring, you'd get $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{3}$ (and $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ instead  of $\frac{1}{\varepsilon^2}$), and everything goes through as well.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** use the [Borel—Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma).

**In  more detail:** fix any $\varepsilon > 0$, and let $A_n=A_n(\varepsilon)$ be the event $\{ \lvert Y_n\rvert > \varepsilon \}$. By Borel—Cantelli, to show that $Y_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{\rm a.s.} 0$, it is sufficient to show
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P} A_n < \infty.
$$

**In even more detail:** *(place your mouse over the gray area to reveal its contents)*

> Since $\lvert Y_n\rvert \leq \varepsilon $ whenever at least one of the $X_i$ satisfies $\lvert X_i\rvert \leq \varepsilon$ (this is a sufficient condition, clearly not necessary), we have $$\mathbb{P} A_n  \leq \mathbb{P}\{ \forall\ 1\leq i \leq n,\ \lvert X_i\rvert > \varepsilon \} = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{P}\{ \lvert X_i\rvert > \varepsilon \} = (1-\varepsilon)^n.$$ It follows that $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{P} A_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-\varepsilon)^n < \infty. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot, great job! Just a minor thing (for sake of completeness), that doesnt't change anything of course: $P(|X|>\varepsilon)=1-\varepsilon$.

Comment: @NikolaosSkout True, I forgot to multiply by the density, $\frac12$. Fixed.